# MySQL VARBINARY WHERE string comparison not working

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, varbinary

I have a MySQL table with fields that are varbinary. They contain strings that are indexed for quick lookup. On one server, lookups seem to work just fine. On another server, they return empty sets. What is causing the discrepancies across the server in the results?

**Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `%s` (
  `url` varbinary(2000) NOT NULL,
  `category` varbinary(64) NOT NULL,
  `type` binary(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`url`(256)),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Result on server 1 (MySQL 5.6.26)**

```
mysql> SELECT `category` FROM `blacklist` WHERE (`category`='porn') AND ((`type`='d' AND `url`='186.59') OR (`type`='d' AND `url`='209.35.186.59') OR (`type`='d' AND `url`='59')) LIMIT 0, 1;                                               
+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
| category |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
| porn     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Result on server 2 (MySQL 5.5.44-0+deb8u1)**

```
mysql> SELECT `category` FROM `blacklist` WHERE (`category`='porn') AND ((`type`='d' AND `url`='186.59') OR (`type`='d' AND `url`='209.35.186.59') OR (`type`='d' AND `url`='59')) LIMIT 0, 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

**Dump values server 1 (usig mysqldump)**

```
INSERT INTO `blacklist` VALUES ('','ads','u'),('1.im.cz/reklama','ads','u'),('12.16.1.10/web_GIF','publicite','u'),('12.16.1.10/~web_ani','publicite','u');
```

**Dump values server 2 (using phpmyadmin)**

```
INSERT INTO `blacklist` (`url`, `category`, `type`) VALUES
('', 0x706f726e, 0x64),
(0x312e696d2e637a2f72656b6c616d61, 0x616473, 0x75),
(0x31322e31362e312e31302f7765625f474946, 0x7075626c6963697465, 0x75),
(0x31322e31362e312e31302f7e7765625f616e69, 0x7075626c6963697465, 0x75);
```

Comment: Why VARBINARY data type for non-binary data? Is that some kind of MySQL special programming trick? (Sorry if it's a stupid question, I don't know MySQL very well.)

Comment: Is there a difference between the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on both servers? Maybe a different (default) setting causes different behavior